# AspectJ declare parents JPanel+

Tags: aspectj, parent, declare

I would like to make a few classes extending `JPanel` actually extend a class of my own in between.

So, I tried this:

```java
public aspect MyAspect
{
   public static class MyPanel
         extends JPanel
   {
   }

   declare parents: JPanel+ extends MyPanel;
}
```

As is, it works. The only issue is that the aspect matches any class extending `JPanel`, whereas I want it to apply only on the `JPanel+` classes from a package.
So I tried this:

```java
public aspect MyAspect
{
   public static class MyPanel
         extends JPanel
   {
   }

   declare parents: my.package..JPanel+ extends MyPanel;
}
```

and it doesn't match any `JPanel+` at all ...

On the other hand I tried to target a particular `JPanel+` class explicitly in a package from `my.package..` and it works for this particular class, so the package path is understood by AspectJ.

I just don't understand why it won't work with `my.package..JPanel+`?
Just `my.package..JPanel` (without the +) would be understandable as no `JPanel` exists there, but why doesn't `my.package..JPanel+` work as expected (by me!)?

By the way, `my.package..*_suffixFilterOnClassName` works, but it really is not ideal in my opinion.

From https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/annotations-decp.html, I understand I could use an annotation as a workaround, but it's not that great either. But it would be better than just the suffix filtering.

Also, it would have been nice if the usual syntax within/withincode & so on from the pointcuts+declare warning+errors would work as for the others pointcuts, but as far as I understand the `declare parents` is implemented with TypePattern only!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is currently not possible using `declare parents` only, but there is a workaround, see below. `my.package..JPanel+` means to look for subclasses of `JPanel` somewhere in a `my.package`, which is not where `JPanel` resides. So the pointcut is simply wrong. You also cannot combine the pointcut with something like `within(my.package..*)`,but only use the naming patterns you already discovered.

There is, however, an undocumented *ajc* compiler parameter `-xmlConfigured`, which is also supported by [AspectJ Maven Plugin](https://github.com/dev-aspectj/aspectj-maven-plugin), see [here](https://dev-aspectj.github.io/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#xmlConfigured) for details.

**Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:%7E:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).

I have recorded as much as I know about `-xmlConfigured` in the old [AspectJ Bugzilla issue 455014](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014). Feel free to fully read it and also scroll to the bottom for updated links to mailing list posts no longer available under the old URLs.

What you specifically need is [**aspect scoping in aop.xml**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014#c3) (Just Ctrl-F search for "scoping" on the page for follow-up information near the bottom).

I.e., something like your original `declare parents: JPanel+ extends MyPanel` incombination with that compiler switch and something like this in *aop.xml* should do the job:

```xml
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="my.aspects.MyAspect" scope="my.package..*"/>
    <!-- other aspects go here, with or without scope -->
  </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

---

**Update:**

Actually, it is a mystery to me why `JPanel+ extends MyPanel` worked for you at all. For me it only does when compiling from Eclipse, but not when compiling from command line. Using ajc, there is a compilation error: `'javax.swing.JPanel'can not extend itself`. I also do not see any obvious way to suppress it. The error is explained easily: `SomeClass+` always includes `SomeClass` itself. Therefore, you will see this compilation error when using the command line or a build tool like Maven, Ant or Gradle.

As a workaround, I am using:

```java
declare parents: (!@JavaBean JPanel+) extends MyPanel;
```

Or, if you want to be very precise:

```java
declare parents: (!@JavaBean(defaultProperty = "UI", description = "A generic lightweight container.") JPanel+) extends MyPanel;
```

I got this idea, looking at the parent class `JPanel`:

```java
@JavaBean(defaultProperty = "UI", description = "A generic lightweight container.")
@SuppressWarnings("serial") // Same-version serialization only
public class JPanel extends JComponent implements Accessible {
  // ...
}
```

You just need to make sure that your subclasses do not have the exact same annotation. BTW, you cannot use `@SuppressWarnings` for exclusion, because it has source retention.

Another thing I noticed is, that somehow scoping via *aop.xml* does not seem to be working for me. I will be busy today, so I am not sure when I can investigate this, but I want to look into it another time.

---

**Update 2:**

I experimented some more and found out that, as I also just wrote in a [Bugzilla comment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=455014#c8), aspect scoping never seems to have been implemented for ITD (inter-type declaration) and only has an effect on regular pointcuts. I.e., with regard to `declare parents` we are kind of back to square one, having to resort to naming patterns.

I created a feature request for XML-based aspect scoping to also work for ITD as [AspectJ issue #253](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/issues/253).

Comment: Please note my update.

Comment: Please also note update 2.

Comment: **Update:** AJC option `-xmlConfigured` is now documented [here](https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/devguide/ajc.html#ajc_options:~:text=%2DxmlConfigured%20%3Cfiles%3E).